# Prevent update of only some columns using SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, datatable, sqldataadapter

What I need is to prevent the update of some columns. I need that fields but I must be sure that these won't be updated even by error.
So is there a property to be set to have these fields only in a sort of read-only status?
Just to be more clear, my query result is made by four fields:

trackingNumber,
trackingStatus,
shippingCode,
shippingDate

The first two will be updated, but the last two won't be modified and I want to be sure that even for error they couldn't be changed.

Is there a way?

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> GetTrackingShippingInfo(string carrierCode, DateTime date) {

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format(@"
            (   SELECT  salesShipment.[Shipping Agent Ref_]             as trackingNumber,
                        salesShipment.[Tracking Status]                 as trackingStatus,
                        salesShipment.[No_]                             as shippingCode,
                        salesShipment.[Posting Date]                    as shippingDate

                FROM    {0}.[{1}$Sales Shipment Header] as salesShipment

                WHERE   salesShipment.[Shipping Agent Code] = @carrierCode AND
                        salesShipment.[Posting Date] = @date AND
                        salesShipment.[Export to Carrier] > 0 AND
                        salesShipment.[Location Code] = @departureWarehouse
            )

            UNION ALL

            (   SELECT  transferShipment.[Shipping Agent Ref_]          as trackingNumber,
                        transferShipment.[Tracking Status]              as trackingStatus,
                        transferShipment.[No_]                          as shippingCode,
                        transferShipment.[Posting Date]                 as shippingDate

                FROM    {0}.[{1}$Transfer Shipment Header] as transferShipment

                WHERE   transferShipment.[Shipping Agent Code] = @carrierCode AND 
                        transferShipment.[Tipo Soggetto 1] = 1 AND 
                        transferShipment.[Posting Date] = @date AND 
                        transferShipment.[Export to Carrier] > 0 AND 
                        transferShipment.[Transfer-from Code] = @departureWarehouse
            )", navDbPrefix, navCompany));

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@carrierCode", carrierCode);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", date));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@departureWarehouse", "MP");

        Dictionary<string, object> selectResult = DbHelper.ExecuteSelectForUpdateQuery(cmd);
        return selectResult;
    }


    public static void UpdateTrackingShippingInfo(DataTable dataTable, SqlDataAdapter adapter) {
        try
        {
            DbHelper.BeginTransaction();
            DbHelper.ExecuteUpdate(dataTable, adapter);
            DbHelper.CommmitTransaction();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            DbHelper.RollbackTransaction();
            log.Error("Failed update query. Rollback executed");
            log.Error(e.ToString());
        }
    }

public static void ExecuteUpdate(DataTable data, SqlDataAdapter adapter)
    {
        SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder;
        cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
        log.Debug(cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand().CommandText);
        adapter.Update(data);
    }
```

Comment: can you show us your code so that we can see what \ how your doing this

Comment: How do you create your commandText? Just don't add them to command text

Comment: In the SqlDataAdapter you will find SqlDataAdapter.UpdateCommand which contains the update statement .. just include only what you need to update

Comment: @SimonPrice Sorry, I've just updated the post.

Comment: @HesamFaridmehr I did not modify the update command, I've just used the same dataTable with the new value and the same adapter that came from the select query

Answer (score 0):

Here Is microsoft example to set the update parameters in your SQLDataAdapter for All CRUD operations :

```
public static SqlDataAdapter CreateCustomerAdapter(
    SqlConnection connection)
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

    // Create the SelectCommand.
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers " +
        "WHERE Country = @Country AND City = @City", connection);

    // Add the parameters for the SelectCommand.
    command.Parameters.Add("@Country", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15);
    command.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15);

    adapter.SelectCommand = command;

    // Create the InsertCommand.
    command = new SqlCommand(
        "INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerID, CompanyName) " +
        "VALUES (@CustomerID, @CompanyName)", connection);

    // Add the parameters for the InsertCommand.
    command.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
    command.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40, "CompanyName");

    adapter.InsertCommand = command;

    // Create the UpdateCommand.
    command = new SqlCommand(
        "UPDATE Customers SET CustomerID = @CustomerID, CompanyName = @CompanyName " +
        "WHERE CustomerID = @oldCustomerID", connection);

    // Add the parameters for the UpdateCommand.
    command.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
    command.Parameters.Add("@CompanyName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40, "CompanyName");
    SqlParameter parameter = command.Parameters.Add(
        "@oldCustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
    parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

    adapter.UpdateCommand = command;

    // Create the DeleteCommand.
    command = new SqlCommand(
        "DELETE FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID", connection);

    // Add the parameters for the DeleteCommand.
    parameter = command.Parameters.Add(
        "@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar, 5, "CustomerID");
    parameter.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

    adapter.DeleteCommand = command;

    return adapter;
}
```

So for the update your require just apply only the columns you need with the required params.